# Apply function with parameters on each element of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with several columns. One column has entries with values that can be negative or positive.
I'd like to apply a function on every entry in this column so that in case it is negative it gets set to 0 and otherwise the value should stay as it is.

my idea was the following:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3,4,5),"value" = c(1,-1,0,2,-2))

f <- function(value) {
  if (value > 0 ){
    return(value)
  }
  else return(0)
}
```

and then use something like the apply function on the "value" column of the dataframe.

eg:

```
df$newValue <- apply(df, f(df$value))
```

I'm not sure its the right approach though as I don't get it to work. Probably having a wrong understanding of "apply" as well

Comment: apply is not needed here : `df$newValue <- ifelse(df$value>0,value,0)` or `df$value <- pmax(df$value,0)`

Comment: @digEmAll works for me, thanks. only that you have to put the `df$newValue` as parameter again. `df$newValue <- ifelse(df$value>0,df$value,0)`

Comment: yep, sorry my mistake, I forgot `df$` before value in the ifelse ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it just for `value`:

```
df$value[df$value<0] <- 0
```

For a `newvalue`:

```
df$newvalue <- df$value # first copy all values
df$newvalue[df$value<0] <- 0 # change by the rule
```

or for all columns, you just need:

```
df[df<0] <- 0
#   ID value
# 1  1     1
# 2  2     0
# 3  3     0
# 4  4     2
# 5  5     0
```

Because `df<0` will get you `TRUE` where that condition is met, in all columns:

```
df<0
        ID value
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I only want to apply it on one column though, not the entire dataframe

Comment: then you just need to specify it:`df$value[df$value<0] <- 0`

Comment: this works well with overriding `df$value` what if I'd like to put it in `df$NewValue` ?

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry if I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use function inside sapply as lamda instead of defining it separately :

```
sapply(df$value,function(x){
  if (x > 0 ){
    return(x)
  }
  else return(0)
})
```

Comment: I get the following Error: `Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`